# Why can't I reference something on 'this' but I can when I use var?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

Sorry I'm not even sure how to phrase this question or what I should even search for (Bit of a Javascript newbie), best way to explain is probably to show you the code. I'm trying to use the GrovePI Node library (https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/tree/master/Software/NodeJS) but I want to abstract the 'board' into a class with prototypes so that I can reference the board from a number of places.

The code below works up until a point. 'board' is defined and when `board.init()` is called, we get the version printed successfully.

```
var GrovePiBoard = function() {

    this.commands = GrovePi.commands;
    var board = new GrovePi.board({
        debug: true,
        onError: function(err){
            console.log('GrovePiBoard.js: Something went wrong');
            console.log(err)
        },
        onInit: function(res) {
            if(res){
                console.log('GrovePiBoard.js: GrovePi Version :: ' + board.version());
            } else {
                console.log('GrovePiBoard.js: res is false');
            }
       }
    });
    // This works
    board.init();
};

GrovePiBoard.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log('Initialising board');
    // I want to do board.init() here.
};
```

However, I really want to be able to access the board object on the init prototype function. Something like this..

```
var GrovePiBoard = function() {
    this.commands = GrovePi.commands;
    this.board = new GrovePi.board({
        debug: true,
        onError: function(err){
            console.log('GrovePiBoard.js: Something went wrong');
            console.log(err)
        },
        onInit: function(res) {
            if(res){
                console.log('GrovePiBoard.js: GrovePi Version :: ' + this.board.version());
            } else {
                console.log('GrovePiBoard.js: res is false');
            }
       }
 });
// This doesn't work here
this.board.init();
};

GrovePiBoard.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log('Initialising board');
    // This doesn't work either
    this.board.init();
};
```

When running the code above I get `ReferenceError: board is not defined` as soon as `this.board.init();` is called.

Why can't I put board onto 'this' then reference it from a prototype?

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you are trying to do. To me this looks like you are over-complicating things and then get confused by how complicated everything is.

Comment: @Tomalak I think I get the question :-) see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is doable, you might want to look at your initial design. If you use `prototype.init` you are looking for a constructor functionality.

The init runs together with you function (when it's called)

Look at this example, how the function and init are called and used.

```
function GrovePiBoard() {
  var results = this.init.apply(this, arguments); // call the init including the arguments
  console.log('The actual function, init returned: ' + results);
}

GrovePiBoard.prototype.init = function() {
  console.log('The init function');
  return 'Im returned from the init';
};

var GrovePiBoard = new GrovePiBoard();
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsbin.com/worisikobo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: an explanation would improve this answer

Comment: Working on that right now :-P
Edit will be there soon

Comment: @BobvanLuijt Thanks, that actually helped a lot and I've got it working!

Comment: @jpwsutton you are welcome, please don't forget to upvote my answer and select it by clicking the green checkbox ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`this.board.init();`

should be something like this:

`Board = new GrovePiBoard();
Board.init();`